# Why is an element separable only if it is of the form $\alpha^p$ for some $\alpha$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

Here is a problem from Allan Clark's Abstract Algebra book:

> Let $F$ be a field, $p > 0$ the characteristic of $F$ and $E$ a finite algebraic extension of $F$. Denote by $E^{(p)}$ the minimal subfield of $E$ containing $F$ such that $E^{(p)}$ contains every element of the form $\alpha^p$ for $\alpha \in E$. Prove that $E$ is separable if and only if $E = E^{(p)}$.

Firstly, I'm confused as to the meaning of "finite algebraic extension". Is it simply supposed to mean that $E$ is finite and algebraic? Because that would mean the "algebraic" part is superfluous, as all finite extensions are algebraic. Additionally, $E$ is then immediately perfect, so the condition $E^{(p)} = E$ holds trivially.

I've been able to deduce, here, that the field $E \setminus F$ is perfect in the case that $E^{(p)} = E$. This is because every element of $E \setminus F$ is of the form $\alpha^p$ (otherwise $E^{(p})$ would not be minimal) and so the mapping $\varphi(x) = x^p$ is an automorphism on $E \setminus F$. It does not follow, however, that $E$ itself is perfect, as some element of $F$ need not be of this form (we require $E^{(p)}$ to contain $F$ in its entirety, so the minimality argument does not apply).

I don't see how to deduce anything from this observation.

Comment: $p > 0$ and $p$ is the characteristic of the fields $E$ and $F$, correct? I think $\mathbb{F}_7 / \mathbb{F}_7$ is separable, but not every element of $\mathbb{F}_7$ is a cube, for example...

Comment: 1. Yes, "finite algebraic" could be just "finite", but algebraic is added for emphasis. 2. The claim that $E$ is "immediatley perfect", though, is not true. For example, if $F=\mathbb{F}_{p}(x)$ is the field of rational functions with coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_p$, then $E=F(x^{1/p})$ is a a finite algebraic extension of $F$, but is not perfect, since $x^{1/p}$ is not a $p$th power.

Comment: Oh, I see your confusion: "finite" is "finite *extension* that is algebraic", not "finite field that is algebraic".

Comment: $E\setminus F$ is not a field; it doesn't even contain $0$ or $1$...

Comment: @stillconfused Right. I'll add that now. Not sure how I managed to forget that.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Oh, right. I understand what is meant by "finite extension" now. It's still true, I think, that $\varphi: E \setminus F \to E \setminus F$ is a bijective function (and could be considered a homorphism on $E$ that fixes the set $E \setminus F$).